# C# Many longrunning tasks in parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I would like to scrape data from one site, so because rapidity is important for my project i must run tasks in parallel. I have a method like this:

```
public void UpdateData(List<string> myList)
{
    while(true)
    { 
      ...
      ...
    }
}
```

And i would like to call the method with different arguments from buttonClick Event so i used this code:

```
var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateData(myList1), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, uiContext); 
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateData(myList2), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, uiContext);
```

The result is after first calling of tasks only the first one continues to update the argument(myList1).
Where is the problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat Perhaps Thread.Sleep() is because of add gap between the requests. Websites blocks uncommon behaviors like to much request per second ...

Comment: i would like to run every 10 secs

Comment: If you want to run something "every x seconds", then maybe use a timer instead of infinite loop + sleep?

Comment: Either use threads or tasks, you are trying to use both.

Comment: I would like to parse data from website that updates its content with javascript so i must store the updated data in my lists . That is why i chose task.factory.StartNew and must run many times simultaneously

Comment: @HansKeﬆing what impact does it have on Task library?

Comment: @ggeorge You wouldn't need to explicitly use Tasks, some timers already execute their tick-handlers of a separate thread. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers

Comment: @Neil I removed Thread.Sleep but nothing new

Comment: @ggeorge what are you trying to do? What does `UpdateData` actually do? Trying to perform multiple database operations in parallel won't improve performance, it will probalby *harm* it due to increased blocking. Improving the query, adding indexes can result in 10, 100 times better performance

Comment: @ggeorge besides, the technique or class you need use depends a *lot* on what the problem is. If you want asynchronous event handlers, use `async/await`. You almost never need Task.`Factory.StartNew` these days, and certainly not `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Firstly i am greek too. Do you want to chat in greek somewhere?

Comment: @ggeorge another strange thing: `while(true)`. That doesn't make much sense, tasks aren't threads. They do their job then stop. If you have a list of inputs, once you process them you just exit. There's no need to use `while(true)` unless the actual code does something strange

Comment: @ggeorge dotnetzone's slack channel (https://slack-dotnetzone.herokuapp.com/), but slack isn't all that great for posting code. Besides, the people involved in the comments would want to know what's going on. I'd gladly chat but we'll have to update the question afterwards to make it clearer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we can chat now and after we can post here. I post my email in slack channel what have to do now? I would like to speak to you in greek for better explanation .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, with async/await i solve my problem .

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly asking the Task Scheduler to run tasks on UI context. There is only one UI context, so only one thread will run at a time.

1. Perform your tasks on non-UI context
2. When you need the UI context, marshal the calls as needed